# pool.apply_async with multiple parameters

Tags: python, multithreading, tuples, argument-unpacking

The below code should call two databases at the same time. I tried to do it with 
ThreadPool but run into some difficulties. pool.apply_async doesn't seem to allow multiple parameters, so I put them into a tuple and then try to unpack them. Is this the right approach or is there a better solution?

The list of tuples is defined in params=... and the tuples have 3 entries. I would expect the function to be called twice, each time with 3 parameters.

```
def get_sql(self, *params):  # run with risk
    self.logger.info(len(params))
    sql=params[0]
    schema=params[1]
    db=params[2]
    self.logger.info("Running SQL with schema: {0}".format(schema))
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, db)
    return df

def compare_prod_uat(self):
    self.connect_dbrs_prod_db()
    self.connect_dbrs_uat_db()
    self.logger.info("connected to UAT and PROD database")

    sql = """ SELECT * FROM TABLE """

    params = [(sql, "DF_RISK_PRD_OWNER", self.db_dbrs_prod), (sql, "DF_RISK_CUAT_OWNER", self.db_dbrs_uat)]
    pool = ThreadPool(processes=2)
    self.logger.info("Calling Pool")
    result_prod = pool.apply_async(self.get_sql, (sql, "DF_RISK_PRD_OWNER", self.db_dbrs_prod))
    result_uat = pool.apply_async(self.get_sql, (sql, "DF_RISK_CUAT_OWNER", self.db_dbrs_uat))

    # df_prod = self.get_sql(sql, "DF_RISK_PRD_OWNER", self.db_dbrs_prod)
    # df_cuat = self.get_sql(sql, "DF_RISK_CUAT_OWNER", self.db_dbrs_uat)


    self.logger.info("Get return from uat")
    df1 = result_uat.get()  # get return value from the database call

    self.logger.info("Get return from prod")
    df2 = result_prod.get()  # get second return value from the database call


    return df1, df2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be many things wrong, but if you add

```
print params
```

as the first line of your get_sql, you'll see that you send in a tuple  (sql, [(sql, "DF_RISK_PRD_OWNER", self.db_dbrs_prod), (sql, .....)])

So yes, length of params is always two, the first parameter being "sql" whatever that is in your implementation, and the second being an array of tuples of length three. I don't understand why you are sending (sql,params) instead of just (params,) as "sql" seems to be there in the array elements. If it needs to be there, your array is in params[1].

However, I don't understand how your worker function would traverse this array. It seems to be built to execute only one sql statement as it doesn't have a for loop.  Maybe you intended to do the for loop in your compare_prod_uat function and spawn as many workers as you have elements in your array? I don't know but it currently doesn't make much sense.

The parameter issue can be fixed by this, though.

Comment: I removed SQL as you correctly suggested, but now the function ends up with a list that has 3 entries of pairs of tuples instead of just 3 entries in param with which the function should be called twice.

Comment: Could you give an example of the output it now creates?

Comment: is your intention to call get_sql as many times as you have items in your params list?  If this is the case, see the last part of my answer above.  Apply_async does not do that for you. Instead, you need to have a for loop through your params, then call apply_async and send only one tuple of three each time.  Of course, you need to change your result handling as well, as you need to collect results from possibly several calls to apply_async.